# Excel VBA - Count number of rows for Filtered Table . Keep getting 4 instead of 0

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to count the row after I filter the table, but keep getting 4 instead of 0. So I'm not sure where I got the code wrong?

```
Sub Test_filter()

' Test_filter Macro

    Rows("4:4").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$F$53").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="14,982"
    Range("M54") = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count

End Sub
```

And when I filter the result, even though I see 0 rows, but it keeps giving me 4 for the counted rows. SO i'm not sure why?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post code and data as text, not images. You will get more and better responses if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the used range to do the count. Change to the filtered range e.g.

```
Range("M54") = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$F$53").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
```

Subtract 1 to remove header.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you QHarr. It works great. If I try to loop this code for other files within the folder, is there a way for me to generalize the filtered range so that it can be applied to different workbooks with different sizes of table?